# Generare swagger.json from annotations during build

Tags: sbt, swagger

I have a Scala application that uses [Swagger Akka HTTP](https://github.com/swagger-akka-http/swagger-akka-http) for generating swagger.json in my project. It works, however I have some issues with it:

- it uses runtime reflection, as far as I can tell the only place in my project that relies on it
- as a result it is one of things that prevents me from using GraalVM's native image (when I run native image it simply breaks)
- it introduces a lot of dependencies that are not used anywhere else (e.g. Jackson serialization - I use Circe and Jaws for handling JSONs)

I am looking for a way of generating the swagger.json file during build, e.g. as a SBT task that I can run when I update routes.

I already saw [sbt-swagger](https://github.com/hootsuite/sbt-swagger) but it have not been updated for 2 years, so I won't run on sbt 1.+.

Are there some scripts, gists or docs that I have missed? I ideally want to be able to feed Swagger annotation processor with a package prefix, have it scan class files and output file to specified place.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I built my own plugin https://github.com/scalalandio/sbt-swagger-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a lack of better option I wrote my own sbt: [sbt-swagger-2](https://github.com/scalalandio/sbt-swagger-2).

You add it to `plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("io.scalaland" % "sbt-swagger-2" % sbtSwagger2Version)
```

and then you define how to generate each `swagger.json` file

```
// API v1
swaggerOutputs += Swagger.Output(
  inputFilter = clazz => Set(
    "backend.healthcheck",
    "backend.auth",
    "backend.api.v1"
  ).exists(prefix => clazz.getName.startsWith(prefix)),
  output = (Compile / classDirectory).value / "docs" / "v1" / "swagger.json",
  host = "http://localhost",
  schemes = List(Swagger.Scheme.HTTP, Swagger.Scheme.HTTPS),
  securitySchemeDefinitions = Map("token" -> new Swagger.OAuth2Definition().password("/auth")),
  info = Swagger.Info(
    title = "Backend API v1",
    version = version.value,
    description = """V1 API description""".stripMargin
  )
)

// API v2
swaggerOutputs += Swagger.Output(
  inputFilter = clazz => Set(
    "backend.healthcheck",
    "backend.auth",
    "backend.api.v2"
  ).exists(prefix => clazz.getName.startsWith(prefix)),
  ...
)
```

It's not perfect, but better than nothing.

Other things worth considering are frameworks like [endpoints](https://github.com/julienrf/endpoints) or generatinh Akka HTTP from `swagger.json` (but then you have to maintain this file manually).

Comment: In case someone finds this answer: I discontinued the Swagger plugin as I found usage of Swagger Core library to be atrocious. I moved to usage of Endpoint4s or Tapir libraries for describing my endpoints and then interpreting them into whatever server I need, while also generating `swagger.json` out of it. While it did require me to rewrite a lot of code it quickly paid back, as it made it easier for me to test endpoints, document them and avoid many bugs of Swagger Core library that I met regularly when using ADTs.